# Is だ (plain form of です) omittable?

Tags: grammar, usage, copula

After studying copula verbs `だ` and `です` in japanese grammar books by myself a couple of months ago, I was under the impresion that `だ` is omittable as it is implied by the context.

Moving on, I recently began reviewing `na-adj` and `i-adj` with a different book, and found out plain non-past form of `i-adj` are conjugated **without** `だ` while plain non-past `na-adj` are conjugated **with** `だ`.

Examples would be:

`i-adj: この時計は大きい`

`na-adj: 彼女が好きだ`

That being said, it `だ` only used with `na-adj` or  can it be used with `i-adj` and ommitted whenever the speakers wants to?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**だ is not the plain form of です.**  They're related, but you can't use だ everywhere you can use です, so calling one the plain form of the other doesn't work.

です has two functions:

1. As a polite copula, similar to だ:

   > りんご**だ**　→　りんご**です**　（noun）
   >   きれい**だ**　→　きれい**です**　（na-adj）
2. As a politeness marker, following i-adjs:

   > うつくしい　→　うつくしい**です**　（i-adj)

i-adjs form complete predicates on their own, and there's no need to add a copula to them:

> ＊うつくしい**だ**　　　←　i-adj+copula, ungrammatical
>   　うつくしい**です**　　←　i-adj+politeness marker, OK

There's another difference between the two forms.  As copulas, だ and です inflect for tense:

> りんご**だった**　→　りんご**でした**　（noun）
>   きれい**だった**　→　きれい**でした**　（na-adj）

But as a politeness marker, です does not inflect; the word before it does:

> うつくし**かった**　→　うつくし**かったです**　（i-adj）

It's true that you can generally omit sentence-final だ in informal style.  It's also true that you must omit sentence-final だ before certain particles such as か and さ.  But when you say うつくしい without だ, that **does not mean だ is omitted**; it was never there in the first place, and it's ungrammatical to add it.

Comment: As a matter of fact, いいです and the like are a modern construction. In the old system, which would have had ようございます（よかったです＞ようございました), it is very easy to analyse です as the polite form of だ. It's probably better to view there as being two です: one is the polite form of だ; the other is a politeness marker for 形容詞.

Answer (score 5):

だ can be dropped after i-adj because the final い in i-adj, or its conjugations, carries the same meaning as the copula itself.

In na-adj, the final な--used as a link from the adjective to nouns or noun phrases--is etymologically derived from the copula. ( In 古語, the link is more easily understood. Changes to the language overtime obfuscated the connection, barring some regional accents near Nagoya. ) It's use is limited to linking adjectivals to nominals, however, and therefore is no longer used in the sentence final form. ( Not to be confused with the sentence final な that indicates reflection--asking one's self a question internally--as in 俺の説明がくどいな… )

Also, the だ form of the copula is used in casual speech and therefore can be dropped as a matter of style--just like in casual American English.

vis. "What's that?" "Bread." versus the less curt, "It's bread".

Comment: So, for i-adj, だ **can** or **must** be dropped?  for na-adj, **must** it be used?  for any other case, can it be dropped?

Comment: For i-adj, the だ form of the copula must be dropped. More properly, it must never be there in the first place, because the い in i-adj is a copula. So, putting both would be like saying, "My pizza is is cold."

Comment: Other forms of the coupla are okay after i-adj ever, because they indicate tone ( politeness, formality, etc. ). So, 寒いです is fine, because the い serves as a copula modifying the adjectival, and the です indicates tone for the entire phrase--in this case, neither polite nor informal.

Comment: When to drop the copula in other cases is a matter of style. For example, when it's appropriate to say, "Bread," versus when it's appropriate to say, "It's bread." For that, I would recommend simply consuming as much Japanese media as possible. ( Emphatically, not just manga and anime. ) For example, I'm an American from a blue collar city, so I liked dropping the copula a lot. People in blue collar parts of Tokyo were easier for me to talk to; they tend to be curt, compared to their Yamanote counterparts on the upper west side. My grandmother, on the other hand, is very upperclass; ...

Comment: ( continued ) My grandmother came from an old, elite Tokyo family. So, to this day she readily jumps into super formal Japanese ( vis. そうでございますか, で being the gerund of the copula, ございます being a formal word indicating existence. ) Next to her, dropping the copula makes me feel very, very curt.

Comment: If you'd like a good book on this stuff, I recommend getting all three volumes of "Japanese: the spoken language" by Mari Noda. They do an incredible job of crystallizing the linguistics of the copula--and all other fundamental, spoken Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

Just some observations. Everything is omittable in Japanese, like in many languages; which adds some spice. Any sentence heavily relies on context, so in informal speech people can spell just a meaningful half of the sentence. Still It does not mean the sentence is correct.
For me, personally, the difficulty is finding out where can you omitt だ or である in formal (not ceremonial) writing, i.e. reports and manuals. Using である too often is discouraged, despite basic rules; so I try finalizing sentences with other verbs in るform. When you use です, or で~~ます you usually add it by intention to honor the opponent. So there is no reason for omitting です; rather replace it with だ by the rules, or when avoiding text bloating.
And yes, both です and だ probably have (there are theories) similar origins, somewhat related to the universal verb "be", ある, while です is a reduction of its honorific forms. Therefore the usage became not exactly equivalent. Another minor theory I've seen, is that they come from different verbs, "be" and "do". For instance in Kansay there was a ”や” particle in place of だ, which suspiciously resembles "やる"(I could not confirm it yet). And Kansai dialect has roots in very old capital Japanese.