# Would it be gramatically correct to say 学校は行きます as opposed to 学校に行きます

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-は

My understanding is that 学校**は**行きます would mean: As for school, I will go there.

While 学校**に**行きます is: I will go to school.

But is this the first sentence ever used? Or even grammatically correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, 学校は行きます is grammatically correct and natural. But this has a clearly contrastive meaning. The sentence implies something like this:

> 学校は行きます。
> (I said I won't go to the dentist but) I will go (at least) to school.

As a basic rule, a contrastive-は *replaces* が and を, but *attaches* other particles such as に, へ, で, から and まで. Still, when a contrastive-は comes at the beginning of a sentence, the associated particle can be omitted with the aid of the context. We even have [eel sentences (うなぎ文)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61651/5010).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the sentence is strictly incorrect from a grammatical point of view, but I doubt anyone would say it.

On the other hand, what is definitely used is the following:

> 学校**には**行きます。

You would add the は without dropping the に if your intention is to highlight that you specifically go to the school (as opposed or in contrast to somewhere else). But に is still required for this to work.